# Blurry text in Unity UI at default scale

Tags: unity, gui, fonts

I'm working on a VR (GoogleVR Cardboard) game, and need to include UI elements within it.

Ever since I first learned how to use Unity's UI elements, I've been limping around what seems to be a major problem: at the default (1,1,1) scale, literally everything involving fonts that I add to a world-space Canvas ends up looking like scaled, blurry bitmaps.

I can kludge around the problem by manually changing the scale of everything UI-related to (0.1, 0.1, 0.1) and multiplying the dimensions of everything by 10... but I can't believe this is how Unity's UI editing is ***intended*** to work by design.

Somewhere along the line, I must have overlooked something major. The question is... what? Is there an option somewhere to either make Unity render fonts at a higher resolution, or to at least change the default scale for new items from (1,1,1) to (0.1, 0.1, 0.1) & multiply all the default dimensions for new UI items by 10?

Comment: try using text mesh pro

Comment: I know what you are talking about first hand.  Use TextMeshPro as @comphonia mentioned.  You can also do the hack you mentioned in your question.  I have done both of those with success, the former being the better option.